# What is the difference between networkid 3 and testnet?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, networkid

I have geth 1.5.4 installed on my ubuntu box. Here is the geth command line documentation for networkid:

> --networkid value                   Network identifier (integer, 0=Olympic (disused), 1=Frontier, 2=Morden (disused), 3=Ropsten) (default: 1)

So, to connect to the Ropsten network, I started geth with `--networkid 3`.

> geth --fast --networkid 3 console

However, it did not connect to the Ropsten network at all. My node started syncing but not sure what network it connected to. When I don't specify networkid but just pass --testnet:

> geth --fast --testnet console

it connects to Ropsten network correctly and starts syncing.

What is the difference between specifying `--testnet` vs `--networkid 3`?

Answer (score 5):

In addition to `--networkid 3` starting geth with `--testnet` also makes sure that you use the correct genesis node for Ropsten.

You can start Ropsten also this way:

```
geth init ropsten_genesis.json && geth --networkid 3
```

Answer (score 1):

`--networkid 3` is the new testnet specifically, Ropsten. 1 is the main blockchain and 2 is the old testnet, morden.

When you use `geth --networkid 3`, it sets the default testnet to Ropsten, so after you've done it once, `--testnet` will bring you on Ropsten.

Comment: I just tried restarting geth without --testnet but with --networkid 3 and it did NOT connect to Ropsten network. So, I am still not sure what the difference between the two is.

Comment: This is missing key parts of the answer.  @phologratos has it right, I think.