# What's the difference between Olympic, Morden and Ropsten?

Tags: testnets, morden, ropsten, networkid

Canonical question about the public Ethereum testnets. What's the difference between Olympic, Morden and Ropsten?

What are their network IDs, which ones are still considered active?

Comment: for the Ids : http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10448/what-is-the-difference-between-networkid-3-and-testnet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Olympic** has the network ID `0`. It was the pre-release testnet launched in early 2015. Somethimes this network is referred to as Ethereum Version 0.9. It was discontinued in July 2015 when Ethereum officially launched and replaced by Morden.

**Morden** has the network ID `2`. It was the first full release testnet launched parallel to *Frontier* public main network with ID `1` in July 2015, the so called Ethereum 1.0. It was later forked to receive the *Homestead* updates. It was recently discontinued due to a testnet-only consensus bug between parity and geth. Also, the difficulty bomb on Morden was already causing blocktimes greater than 30 seconds.

**Ropsten** has the network ID `3`. It was launched in November 2016 and replaces the bugged Morden testnet, and currently runs the latest *Homestead* branded version of Ethereum.

Comment: New Kovan testnet proposal https://github.com/kovan-testnet/proposal