# How to detect if on mainnet or testnet?

Tags: web3js

Is it possible to figure out whether the network is mainnet or testnet (Ropsten) from web3.js? Or through MetaMask?

Comment: Use ES6: await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType((err, network)=> {...});

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Prior to Web 1.0 you can use [web3.version.getNetwork](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3versionnetwork) as following:

```
web3.version.getNetwork((err, netId) => {
  switch (netId) {
    case "1":
      console.log('This is mainnet')
      break
    case "2":
      console.log('This is the deprecated Morden test network.')
      break
    case "3":
      console.log('This is the ropsten test network.')
      break
    default:
      console.log('This is an unknown network.')
  }
})
```

**WEB 1.0** :

Since web 1.0 we have [web3.eth.net.getNetworkType](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-net.html#getnetworktype)
which Guesses the network we are connected to.

```
web3.eth.net.getNetworkType()
.then(console.log);
```

It returns a string referring network's name :

- "main" for main network
- "morden" for the morden test network
- "ropsten" for the ropsten test network
- "private" for undetectable networks.

Comment: Use ES6: await web3.eth.net.getNetworkType((err, network)=>  {...});

Answer (score 9):

[web3.version.network](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3versionnetwork) or the async version web3.version.getNetwork() allow one to directly determine the network ID from web3.js.

Usage is as expected:

```
var network = web3.version.network
```

Network IDs can be found in [this](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155) thread.

Comment: This might lead to exceptions stating that it is no good to access web3 methods synchronously. I had it this way and ran into issues in my rendering of react components, so i changed it to the accepted answer

Comment: web3.version.getNetwork() is asynchronous, for what it's worth.

Comment: youre right of course, but the only code fragment you actually formatted as code is the synchronous version which should be avoided, especially since there is a async variant. Didnt want to make your post down or anything, just wanted to give a helpful sidenote on that topic

Answer (score 8):

For `web3 1.0.0` you should do:

```
web3.eth.net.getId().then(netId => {
  switch (netId) {
    case 1:
      console.log('This is mainnet')
      break
    case 2:
      console.log('This is the deprecated Morden test network.')
      break
    case 3:
      console.log('This is the ropsten test network.')
      break
    default:
      console.log('This is an unknown network.')
  }
})
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [@Badr's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/17211/7866), there are two more test networks, Rinkeby and Kovan:

```
switch (networkId) {
  case "1":
    networkName = "Main";
    break;
  case "2":
   networkName = "Morden";
   break;
  case "3":
    networkName = "Ropsten";
    break;
  case "4":
    networkName = "Rinkeby";
    break;
  case "42":
    networkName = "Kovan";
    break;
  default:
    networkName = "Unknown";
}
```

UPDATE: web3@1.0.0 has a [`web3.eth.net.getNetworkType([callback])`](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-net.html#getnetworktype) function to get a network name guess

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to figure out whether the network is mainnet or testnet
>   (Ropsten) from web3.js?

This has been asked before, and is answered here: [Getting Go-Ethereum current network id](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11308/getting-go-ethereum-current-network-id)

In addition to these suggestions, you could take a look a the [`net_version`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#net_version) RPC call.

> Or through MetaMask?

The main MetaMask pop-up shows the network you're connected to in the top left. It also functions as a drop-down, to allow you to select which network you want it to connect to.